# Why Flutter Hero is strange on iOS device, and is Ok on Android device, How can I fix that?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-animation

On Android device, Hero can support a good effect, like do **alpha and shared element transition** at the same time.

But on iOS device, most likely the Hero will product an effect like do **slide and shared element transition** at the same time, which I think is so strange.

Answer (score 3):

That's because on iOS it use the CupertinoTransition (right to left) , you can override the transition for both platforms.

Add this custom transition when you open your new page.

```
      Navigator.of(context).push(
            PageRouteBuilder<Null>(
                pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
                    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
                  return AnimatedBuilder(
                      animation: animation,
                      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                        return Opacity(
                          opacity: animation.value,
                          child: YourNewPage(),
                        );
                      });
                },
                transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600)),
          );
```